# nuspec.xsd repository types

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-spec

I've seen that it is now possible to download source code of a nuget package, if the package provides that. So I lookuped up the documentation:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/compiler/resources/nuspec.xsd

```
<xs:element name="repository" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="branch" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="commit" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Does anyone know, or is there any further documentation of what I can put into "type"? Because the .xsd only says "string". I know that "git" is a possible option, but I don't see any other options.

Answer (score 1):

*git* is the default

[< RepositoryType>git< /RepositoryType>](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/2c5dd461a853cfb318583a0d33ef5c244003131b/build/config.props#L44)

there seems to be no alternative so far.